# CSS 3 Validation errors for Visual Studio 2010 sp1

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I was just wondering if there is a fix for the following validation errors.

Validation (CSS 3.0): `text-shadow` is not a known CSS property name.
Validation (CSS 3.0): `text-overflow` is not a known CSS property name. 
Validation (CSS 3.0): `none` is not a valid value for the `max-height` property.
Validation (CSS 3.0): `rotate(180deg)` is not a valid value for the `-webkit-transform` property

Now here is the funny part, when I switch it to the CSS 2.1 Validation, I do get a bunch of other warnings about invalid properties( which are css 3.0 properties), but then I don't get these errors: 'none' is not a valid value for the `max-height` property and `rotate(180deg)` is not a valid value for the `-webkit-transform`.

I've installed SP1 and the css3 schema, checked the registry, and everything is how it's supposed to be. I've checked many answers here. Some of them suggest to uncheck 'Detect unknown properties', 'Detect invalid values', or uncheck 'Detect errors', but that's not what I was looking for. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8):

If you install the [Web Standards Update for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 SP1](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a15c3ce9-f58f-42b7-8668-53f6cdc2cd83) and then the  [CSS 3 Intellisense Schema](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7211bcac-091b-4a32-be2d-e797be0db210) that should do the trick.
The first one apparently is missing some of the specifications.

Good Luck. Let me know if that worked for you.

Answer (score 3):

Did you install the Web Standards Update for SP1?

Comment: Oh I forgot to mention about that. I did install the web standards but it got even worse. That's why I uninstalled it. I was getting errors, I mean lots of them like these: Warning 25 Validation (CSS 3.0): '3px' is not a valid value for the '-webkit-box-shadow' property.

Warning 22 Validation (CSS 3.0): '15px' is not a valid value for the '-webkit-box-shadow' property.

Answer (score 0):

To manually add any missing CSS selector properties, you can also manually edit the syntax file, on my system (Visual Web Developer 2010) the file was located at:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\Packages\1033\schemas\CSS\css30.xml
```

Search for the selector that is giving you a false error.

Tip: make a backup of the original first.